# SpringBoot Flyway - More phases of sql patches (running non-breaking and breaking sql patches separately)

Tags: java, spring, flyway

Is it possible to run migrations with flyway in "2 phases" ?

The problem is that I need to make deploy to production server without any outage and SQL migrations are a problem.

I though I can write every (not every SQL patch will be breaking so most of patches) SQL patch 2 times - once without breaking changes (no column drops etc.) and once with breaking change.

So my question is if it is possible with Flyway.

I imagine something like `migrations:migrate --type=non-breaking`  and `migrations:migrate --type=breaking`

And my SQL patch would be named like this:

```
V1_loremIpsum.non-breaking.sql

V1_loremIpsum.breaking.sql
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having two migrations both called `V1__...` won't work as there needs to be an unambiguous ordering, so you will need to rename one of them. If the intention is to run all the non-breaking changes, then do something else such as an application update, then run the breaking ones once the application is confirmed to be up and stable, use the `target` option:

```
V1__loremipsum-nonbreaking-do-these-first.sql
V1_0_1__loremipsum-breaking.sql

/* Only migrates the non-breaking changes */
migrations:migrate --target=1

/* Migrates all - safe to call whether the above has been called or not */
migrations:migrate [--target=latest]
```